# Telerik RadGrid refreshing a single row instead of using Rebind

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am using a RadGrid to display stock information. The data bound is a combination of 2 views and 2 tables. This is quite an intensive query, and the data behind it changes a lot. Now, when I update a value in a single row, I have to Rebind the data to update my grid (I use UpdateValues on the item, but it has no visible effect). This is taking too long to be user-friendly. Is there a simple way to work around it, so I can just update the row which has the changed data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to do that because the Telerik Grid is data bound control - hence to modify its source and refresh the data in the grid UI, you will need to bind all rows.

Dick